# Получить указатель на реальный элемент контейнера через итератор

Tags: c++, g++

У меня следующая задача: нужно переписать часть элементов одного контейнера в другой (в примере переписываются все, но это пример). В примере для простоты int, но в моём коде довольно объёмные объекты, и, само собой, хотелось бы в контейнер-получатель записать указатели, а не переписывать содержимое (исходный контейнер не будет меняться, пока контейнер получатель находится в работе, поэтому указатели точно будут рабочими).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Test
{
    public:

    std::vector<int> testvector = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
    std::vector<int*> ptrvector;


    void testmethod()
    {
        for(auto i:testvector)
            ptrvector.push_back(&i);

        for(auto i:ptrvector)
            std::cout << *i << std::endl;
    }       

};

int main()
{
    Test test;
    test.testmethod();

    return 0;
}
```

Этот код выведет нули вместо всего числового ряда.
Эта строка конечно ошибочна ptrvector.push_back(&i) , т.к. тут записывается адрес итератора, а не объекта из вектора.

Как через итератор i получить указатель?

Comment: А что мешает держать в другом контейнере итераторы, если вы гарантируете их валидность? Синтаксически итератор ничем не отличается от указателя.

Comment: И `&i` — не адрес итератора, а адрес временной переменной, в которую копируется элемент массива.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вариант:

```
void testmethod()
{
    for(auto & i : testvector)   // берем не копию, а ссылку на элемент
        ptrvector.push_back(&i);

    for(auto i:ptrvector)
        std::cout << *i << std::endl;
}
```

Второй вариант, c применением функции [data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data):

```
void testmethod()
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < testvector.size(); ++i)
        ptrvector.push_back(testvector.data() + i);

    for(auto i:ptrvector)
        std::cout << *i << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Первый вариант как раз то, что мне нужно, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Раз вам даются итераторы — и использовать нужно итераторы.

```
vector<int> testvector = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
vector<vector<int>::iterator> ptrvector;

for (auto iter = begin(testvector); iter != end(testvector); ++iter)
    ptrvector.push_back(iter);

for (auto iter : ptrvector)
    cout << *iter << " ";
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/s9CGDN

---

Но этот код достаточно хрупкий. Изменение стартового контейнера инвалидирует итераторы. (Впрочем, оно точно так же инвалидировало бы и указатели.)

---

Вот вам шаблонный код, который работает с [почти] любым типом контейнера.

```
template<typename Container>
auto get_pointers(const Container& c)
{
    vector<decltype(begin(c))> ptrvector;

    for (auto iter = begin(c); iter != end(c); ++iter)
        ptrvector.push_back(iter);

    return ptrvector;
}
```

С этим вы можете писать так:

```
vector<int> testvector = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
auto ptrs1 = get_pointers(testvector);
for (auto p : ptrs1)
    cout << *p << " ";

int testarray[] = { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 10 };
auto ptrs2 = get_pointers(testarray);
for (auto p : ptrs2)
    cout << *p << " ";

unordered_set<int> testset = { 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 20 };
auto ptrs3 = get_pointers(testset);
for (auto p : ptrs3)
    cout << *p << " ";
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/wHxZtM

Answer (score 0):

Стандартные задачи надо решать стандартными же алгоритмами. Для копирования из одного контейнера в другой следовало бы применить `std::copy`/`std::copy_if`. Но так как типы хранимых в контейнерах элементов не могут быть неявно и при этом правильно преобразованы друг в друга, подходящей будет функция [`std::transform`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> testvector = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
    std::vector<int*> ptrvector;

    std::transform(testvector.begin(), testvector.end(), std::back_inserter(ptrvector), 
                   [](int& el) { return &el; });

    for(const int* p: ptrvector)
    {
        std::cout << *p << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

<kbd>[Результат выполнения.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/KYGtGaI0LQxcX0C7)</kbd>